# Test run faster, then my function finish. React, Enzyme + Jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I try to test `function`, that after finish API request shall display `displayModalSuccess`.

```
someFunction = () => {
      displayModalLoading()
      Promise.all([execDelete(something here...)])
      .then(function(){
         displayModalSuccess()
        return({something...}.bind(this))
```

In my test I have tested if `someFunction` is called, and i want to find `succes modal`, but its not there yet.

```
 someFunction: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({}))
    
     .....

     // (my part of test related to topic)
    
     expect(someFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    
     expect(wrapper.find('.t-btn-modal-delete-success').length).toEqual(1);

     ....
```

I have also put `console.log()` into code, and into test. The test `console.log()`, runs first, so that means that `succes modal` is not there yet, when test runs?

How can I make this test succesfull, I guess I have to wait somehow on function to finish?

Im new in testing, happy for every answer.